# Catkin version of rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check

Tags: roslaunch, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a catkin version of the rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check?  The catkin migration guide doesn't show one: [See here](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#Test_Macros)

This is a very good tool for checking that the proper launch dependencies are included.  I think this would still be useful in catkin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64476/catkin-version-of-rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-07**:
+1, If there is not one already, we should create it.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-07**:
I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMake function roslaunch_add_file_check() will be available as of roslaunch 1.9.46.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since @William would almost certainly know if there were already a solution to that migration problem, I took the liberty of opening [ros/catkin#439](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/439) to get it resolved. I need it, too.

If I can figure out how to implement it, I'll submit a patch. But, I can't promise that right now.

**UPDATE**: the catkin maintainer seems to feel that opening a catkin issue for this was a foolish idea. At his direction, I opened a new [ros/ros_comm#241](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/241) ticket for **roslaunch**.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1